# Standard SQL - windows with time constrains

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm running a window function which looks like this on Standard SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM base_query
WHERE
    (
        event_page_type = "product"
        AND (
            -- Monthly price feature
            event_name LIKE "fs_mp_%"
            -- Add to cart events
            OR event_name = "add_to_cart"
        )
    )
/*
    Keep only those add_to_cart events which have a fs_mp event on the same session
*/
QUALIFY MAX(IF(event_name LIKE "fs_mp_%", 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY session_id) = 1
```

What I try to do with this query is get all the `fs_mp_%` like events, and only those `add_to_cart` events which have a `fs_mp_%` event on the same session.

However, this logic doesn't check that the `fs_mp_%` event happened before the `add_to_cart` one. If I wanted to add that logic according to a `server_timestamp` field, how would it look?

Comment: That's not valid ANSI/ISO SQL.

Comment: @jarlh what do you mean? It's Standard SQL

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my way. I need a second condition in the `QUALIFY` statement:

```
QUALIFY
    MAX(IF(event_name LIKE "fs_mp_%", 1, 0)) OVER (session) = 1
    AND MIN(IF(event_name LIKE "fs_mp_%", server_timestamp, "9999-12-31")) OVER (session) < server_timestamp
WINDOW session AS (PARTITION BY session_id)
```